# Cannot connect to localdb in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, localdb

I keep getting this error when I try to do an update-database command in the package manager console:

> ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid.
>   )

My connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BookServiceContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0; Initial Catalog=BookServiceContext-20150228232739; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|BookServiceContext-20150228232739.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I can connect via SSMS 2014 and I can see `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and `(localdb)\ProjectsV12` in the SQL Server Object Explorer.

EDIT

Even when a part of connection string is changed to:
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BookServiceContext-20150228232739.mdf"

It still pulls the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a backslash missing in you connection string:

instead of

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|BookServiceContext-20150228232739.mdf"
```

it should be

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BookServiceContext-20150228232739.mdf"
```

Refer to [Creating a Connection String and Working with SQL Server LocalDB](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string)

**Update**

It turns out that after a `\` wasn't missing but there are too many of them. I was able to reproduce the error by adding another `\` to

```
Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0
```

this means your `Data Source` should be:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0
```

with only one `\`

Comment: With the above changes, it still pulls the same error. The connection string was autogenerated in Visual Studio.

Comment: See my update to the answer. Perhaps it'll still help :-]

Answer (score 0):

**Kindly check your connection string**

```
Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```